# Writing data in csv file using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to write data into a csv file
Rest all the fields are getting written fine , but not the date field can someone please explain me what is going wrong

Here is my code

def writeData(self):

```
    query_string=f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{self.ticker}?period1={self.period1}&period2={self.period2}&interval={self.interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'.format(ticker=self.ticker,period1=self.period1,period2=self.period2,interval=self.interval)

    filename="C:\\Users\\BRBCO\\Downloads\\out.csv"

    url = query_string.replace(" ","")   

    df=pd.read_csv(url)

    df.columns= df.columns.str.lower() 

    df.to_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8',date_format='%s')
```

This is the output of the csv file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI6dc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In 98% of cases, the reason is that the CSV was opened directly with Excel and therefore Microsoft standards apply.

Excel always displays hash marks when the contents of a cell are too wide to be displayed in the cell. You can solve this problem by making the corresponding column wider.

**In general**

- If you want to work with Excel, convert the DataFrame `.to_excel()` or open Excel, import the CSV file via the menu item Data and make your adjustments for interpreting column values.
- Otherwise, you should rather open the CSV in a text editor, which will display the values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, column B in the screenshot is not wide enough so all values show `########`, it's impossible for us to see the actual output values.

Secondly, make sure the datetime values are actually interpreted as datetime datatypes when reading the file. So add `dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True` to the read_csv, and try changing the `dayfirst` parameter to True/False depending on your data.

Finally, when writing datetime values to CSV it's always easier to use ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`, so for example `2022-03-31`, because this is unambiguous and doesn't rely on any arbitrary system settings. You can write ISO date by setting the `date_format` in write_csv.

```
filename="C:\\Users\\BRBCO\\Downloads\\out.csv"

url = query_string.replace(" ", "")   

df=pd.read_csv(url, dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True)

df.columns = df.columns.str.lower() 

df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```